# What is the number of significant digits that BigDecimal is allowing to use - Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

My application is using a double in Java for representing floating point numbers.
double has a limitations of 17 significant digits.
we are considering to refactor the code to use BigDecimal - however i couldn't find any information in the documentation regarding the number of significant digits that BigDecimal is allowing to use.

Any information regarding this will be very helpful, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "probably more digits than you are ever likely to need" ... but strictly speaking there are a couple of limits.

1. The size of your JVM's heap could limit the size of a `BigDecimal` object that can be created.  (You might get an `OutOfMemoryError` ...)
2. For any implementation of `BigDecimal`, there is likely to be an implementation-specific limit due to the classes internal representation.

For the implementation in Java 8, a `BigDecimal` number's representation consists of a `BigInteger` to represent the digits, and an `int` to represent the scale factor.  The javadoc for `BigInteger` states:

> `BigInteger` must support values in the range -2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive) to +2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive) and may support values outside of that range.

So the theoretical maximum number of decimal digits of precision for a `BigDecimal` **in Java 8** is at least log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>2<sup>31</sup> - 1</sup> ).

---

> Any information regarding this will be very helpful.

The definitive source of information is the source code of `BigDecimal` and the classes that it depends on.

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDoc:
[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is `Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.`

So the number of significant digits is infinite and only limited by your memory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: Arbitrary != unbounded.